# Object data source is passing customer object instead of int of customerId on delete method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `GridView` and an `ObjectDataSource` tied together. Everything works great except for the Delete method. It's trying to pass a Customer object instead of the `CustomerId` I told it to.

[image]

Comment: Have you added the data key names to your GridView ?

Comment: Can you post your full GridView code as well?

Comment: Can't you get the customer id from the customer infect and delete it they way?

Comment: Sorry I was on my phone! If it wants to pass the customer object, cant you just accept that in your function and access the customer id to delete it that way?  Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Partha Yes, I do have the data key name specified

Comment: I'm comparing it to a solution that looks the same as mine but the delete works off the customer id (I know, then it's not the same ; ) but I'm not seeing it. And I don' think there anymore code to show. Granted, if I make the parameter a Customer object it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as following:

1- Add `OldValuesParameterFormatString="{0}_Key"` in gridview

2- Change parameter in ods section to:`<asp:Parameter Name="customerid_Key" Type="Int32" />`

3- change the paramater name in delete method to `int customerid_Key`.

I hope this answer help you. (I can not add comment because of my reputation, then I added answer!)